# How can I stop a setInterval to run after executing a AJAX request that replaces that setInterval in the DOM with another setInterval?

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom, timer, setinterval

I am using jQuery and I have some trouble on stopping to work the `setInterval` when performing a AJAX request that returns the same code containing the same `setInterval`. That is:

Given I have the following code:

```
<div id="test_css_id">
  <a id="link_css_id" href="test_url.html">LINK</a>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#link_css_id').click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      $.ajax({
        url:     $(this).attr('href'),
        type:    'PUT',
        success: function(data) {
          $('#test_css_id').replaceWith(data); // Replaces all code including JavaScript with the response data (note: the response data is exactly the same as the code shown here).
        }
      });
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
      var refreshTimer;

      function refreshFunction(){
        $.ajax({
          url:     'test_url.html',
          type:    'GET',
          success: function(data) {
            $('#test_css_id').replaceWith(data); // Replaces all code including JavaScript with the response data (note: the response data is exactly the same as the code shown here).
          },
          complete: function(data) {
            clearInterval(refreshTimer); // Note: This'd not stop the setInterval.
          }
        });
      }

      refreshTimer = setInterval(refreshFunction, 1000); // milliseconds
    });
  </script>
</div>
```

When the AJAX request within the `click` function runs on success then the above code is reloaded (*note*: the rendered `data` in the `replaceWith` is *exactly* the same as the above code, including JavaScript). However the `setInterval` is not "overrode" / "stopped" and so the browser runs one more time that `setInterval` for each time I clicked the`LINK`. The same does not happen when the `refreshFunction` runs. However, depending on the amount of previous click on the `LINK`, even the `refreshFunction` causes the `setInterval` to run more and more.

How can I stop the `setInterval` to run when the AJAX request success so to have only one `setInterval` running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to clear the timer right before you perform the replacement.  For this, you'll need the timer variable to be accessible within the `click` callback as well.  In this case, I have made the timer global, but there are other ways you can do it, I'll leave that up to you.

```
<div id="test_css_id">
  <a id="link_css_id" href="test_url.html">LINK</a>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var refreshTimer;  //******************** Timer is now global
    $('#link_css_id').click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      $.ajax({
        url:     $(this).attr('href'),
        type:    'PUT',
        success: function(data) {
          //************* Clear interval if it exists before replacing code.
          clearInterval(refreshTimer);
          $('#test_css_id').replaceWith(data); // Replaces all code including JavaScript with the response data (note: the response data is exactly the same as the code shown here).
        }
      });
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
      function refreshFunction(){
        $.ajax({
          url:     'test_url.html',
          type:    'GET',
          success: function(data) {
            $('#test_css_id').replaceWith(data); // Replaces all code including JavaScript with the response data (note: the response data is exactly the same as the code shown here).
          },
          complete: function(data) {
            clearInterval(refreshTimer); // Note: This'd not stop the setInterval.
          }
        });
      }

      refreshTimer = setInterval(refreshFunction, 1000); // milliseconds
    });
  </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, your code solved the issue. Can you point out what are other ways you can do it? I know global variables are not good...

Comment: Well, one way is to wrap all of that code into a module (a function object) that is executed immediately: `(function() {...code here...})()`  This will create a function and execute it immediately, which in turn executes all your code within that function object.  Now any vars you declare will be within the scope of the function and not global.

Comment: I come up to http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/principles-of-maintainable-javascript. Maybe it is a good starting read...

Comment: Very good writeup there, a number of different methods you can use depending on your purposes.

Comment: My main purpose is to use the best approach for stability, performance and maintainability, even if I must learn a lot. Now I am reading about Self-Executing Anonymous Function, since you mentioned it, but if you have any other advise or resource, you are welcome.

Comment: I am in trouble when trying to wrap the code into a module, so I post a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18906723/how-can-i-wrap-code-into-a-module-in-order-to-avoid-using-global-variables