# How can I wrap code into a module in order to avoid using global variables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, design-patterns, module, global-variables

After my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18898676/how-can-i-stop-a-setinterval-to-run-after-executing-a-ajax-request-that-replaces), I come up to the following working code that is intended to refresh the DOM periodically by replacing the `<div id="test_css_id">...</div>` itself. The behavior of both AJAX requests present in the below code is to reload the same code itself.

```
<div id="test_css_id">
  <a id="link_css_id" href="test_url.html">LINK</a>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var refreshTimer; 

    $('#link_css_id').click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      $.ajax({
        url:     $(this).attr('href'),
        type:    'PUT',
        success: function(data) {
          clearInterval(refreshTimer);
          $('#test_css_id').replaceWith(data); // Replaces all code including JavaScript with the response data (note: the response data is exactly the same as the code shown here).
        }
      });
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
      function refreshFunction(){
        $.ajax({
          url:     'test_url.html',
          type:    'GET',
          success: function(data) {
            clearInterval(refreshTimer);
            $('#test_css_id').replaceWith(data); // Replaces all code including JavaScript with the response data (note: the response data is exactly the same as the code shown here).
          }
        });
      }

      refreshTimer = setInterval(refreshFunction, 1000);
    });
  </script>
</div>
```

However, as said by the author of the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18901457/824806), "there are other ways you can do it [..] one way is to wrap all of that code into a module". I am not expert in JavaScript but I would like to understand and learn it a little more.

How can I wrap all of that code into a module in order to avoid using global variables?

Answer (score 1):

Your current code looks like this:

```
var refreshTimer; //a global variable

$(...).click(...);
```

To make refreshTimer not global, you need to put it inside a function:

```
function main(){
   var refresherTimer; //this variable is now local to "main"

   $(...).click(...);
}

main();
```

However, doing it this way won't solve the problem completely. While we did get rid of the global variables, we added a new one - the "main" function itself.

The final trick is to turn the "main" function into an anonymous function and invoke it directly. This is the famous "module pattern":

```
(function(){
   var refreshTimer; //local variable to that anonymous function

   $(...).click(...);
}()); //and here we call the function to run the code inside it.
```

The extra parenthesis around everything are important. If you do just `function(){}()` instead of `(function(){}())` then you will get a syntax error.

Comment: Did you really mean that, in order to avoid using global variables, I just have to state `(function(){ <MY_CODE_HERE> }());`?

Comment: Yes. There are two kinds of variables: global variables and local variables (that are local to the function they were defined in). Therefore, the way to get rid of globals is to turn them into locals intead. The `(function(){}()` thing is just a neat way to put a small "throwaway" function around everything.

Comment: Is the way you proposed to get rid of globals a "good general" solution to these kind of issues as-like my? There is some more that I can improve?

Comment: The only way to get rid of globals id to put your code inside a function. The module pattern is just the most straightforward way to do so. Don't worry too much other than that though - your code is fine.

Comment: Do we still need now with the new module system in javascript?

Comment: Due to Javascript's strict backwards compatibility this advice will continue to be valid for the foreseeable future. However, if you are using a Javascript system that supports modules, feel free to use that instead (it is worth noting that there are a bunch of different module systems out there)

Answer (score 0):

[Here's](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html) a nice description of the module pattern in JavaScript.

Comment: I have also read that article, but I am still in trouble when stating the JavaScript module pattern and even using the resulting code that I have written myself (*!*).

Comment: Give me a minute.  I'll try to write yours as an example.